# センサーから取得したデータをスプレットシート(GAS)のWEBAPI経由でデータを書き込みたいけど、反応しない

Tags: python, google-api, google-spreadsheet

ラズパイ側のスクリプト
・一応以下、スプレットシートとの連携はOK
・dataの取得もスクリプト実行する度にできている

怪しい点としては、GoogleスプレットシートのGASを使用したときにAPIが叩ける設定になっているかは不明
一応APIの設定とかは行ったが。。。

```
~
if scanner.delegate.sensorValue is not None:
    #デバイス名
    deviceName = 'EP-BL01'#←スプレッドシートのシート名と同じ名前にする
    #POSTするデータ
    data = {
        'DeviceName': deviceName,
        'Date_Master': str(masterDate),
        'Date': str(date),
        'SensorType': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['SensorType']),
        'Temperature': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['Temperature']),
        'Humidity': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['Humidity']),
        'Light': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['Light']),
        'UV': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['UV']),
        'Pressure': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['Pressure']),
        'Noise': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['Noise']),
        'BatteryVoltage': str(scanner.delegate.sensorValue['BatteryVoltage'])
    }
    #a = {'DeviceName': 'EP-BL01', 'Date_Master': '2020-08-17 21:56:00', 'Date': '2020-08-17 21:56:02.561509', 'SensorType': 'EP', 'Temperature': '28.06', 'Humidity': '65.81', 'Light': '0', 'UV': '0.02', 'Pressure': '1007.8', 'Noise': '40.51', 'BatteryVoltage': '2.9'}
    APIのURL
    #url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/*************/exec'
    #APIにデータをPOST
    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

スプレットシート(GAS)スクリプトは以下
・こちらのシートが全く反応しない
・WEBAPIの設定なのか、以下のスクリプトなのでか、原因不明です

```
var spreadsheetId = '***********************'//←スプレッドシートのID

//Postされたデータを受け取り
function doPost(e){
  var data = [
    e.parameter.Date_Master, // マスター日時     
    e.parameter.Date, // 測定日時    
    e.parameter.Temperature, // 気温    
    e.parameter.Humidity, // 湿度    
    e.parameter.Light, // 照度    
    e.parameter.UV, // UV    
    e.parameter.Pressure, // 圧力    
    e.parameter.Noise, // 騒音    
    e.parameter.BatteryVoltage, // 電池電圧    
    new Date(), // アップロード終了時刻    
  ];
  //取得したデータをログに記載
  Logger.log(new Date());
  //スプレッドシートへのデータ行書き込み
  addData(e.parameter.DeviceName, data);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}

//スプレッドシートへのデータ行書き込み
function addData(sheetName, data){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.appendRow(data);
}
```

以上です。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: こちら解決しました。失礼しました

Comment: 権限の設定ミスでした

Comment: このサイトでは自己回答も歓迎してますので、同じような問題で困った人が参照したときにも役立つよう、解決に至った情報をぜひ個別の回答として投稿してもらえればと思います。